# Non-degenerate bilinear forms and orthogonal bases for free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Given a finite-dimensional free module $M$ over a (commutative) ring $R$, let $(-,-)$ be a symmetric non-degenerate $R$-bilinear map $M \times M \to R$. Will $M$ admit two $R$-module bases, $e_i$ and $e_j$, such that
$$
(e_i,e_j) = c_{ij} \delta_{ij},  ~~ \textrm{ for some } c_{ij} \in R?
$$
To clarify, by non-degeneracy I mean that for any $m \in M$, $\exists$ an $n \in M$ s.t $(m,n) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}$, and the form $(m,n)=2mn$. The image of this form is $2\mathbb{Z}$, and so does not contain $1$, thus a basis as you require does not exist.

This can be generalized to any ring which has a non-invertible element $a$ which is not a zero divisor. Take $M=R$ and the non-degenerate form $(r,s)=ars$.

EDIT: The question can be phrase as is whether any symmetric (non-degenerate) matrix is equivalent to a diagonal matrix. This is not true, for example, take the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the matrix $A=\pmatrix{x&2\\2&x}$. If $A$ would be equivalent to a diagonal matrix $D=\pmatrix{d_1 &\\&d_2}$ then they will have the same determinant (up to $\pm$, so we can assume the determinants are actually the same) and their entries will generate the same ideal ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2293325/1014612)).

Combine this we get $d_1d_2=x^2-4$ and $\langle d_1,d_2\rangle=\langle x,2\rangle$. This is impossible, by direct calculation using $d_1=ax+2b$,$d_2=qx+2r$ we get that (up to $\pm$ and switching $d_1$ and $d_2$) $d_1=x+2$ and $d_2=x-2$. The last contradict the assumption about the ideals.

I hope this solve the question, and sorry again about the mistake.

Comment: @ re'em waxman: Thanks for the answer. However I am not looking for an orthonormal pair of bases, just an orthogonal pair. So for your first example I can take $e_1 = e^1 = 1$ and then $a_{11} = 2$. Of course this will work for any free module of dimension $1$, so any counter example would have to have dimension at least $2$. Any ideas if such a thing can be cooked up?

Comment: I'm so sorry. Your question reduce to Does for any matrix $A$ over $R$ there exists $P,Q$ invertible and $D$ diagonal such $A=PDQ$. This is not always true for general rings as far as I remember. I think $k[x,y]$ can give an example, I will try to think about this tomorrow, Again I am sorry about the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reformulation of the question, and I'll wait for your answer!

Comment: Note that the question is only asking about symmetric (and nondegenerate) bilinear forms, not all matrices. This (very detailed) [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/362434) may also be useful